# trouble with \url and line breaks

Tags: line-breaking, urls

Listing picture credits in a book. Many of them are websites, with long addresses.
Here's one:

\figc{II056}:  Victoria and Albert Museum.\url{https://collections.vam.ac.uk/item/O70273/model-for-the-funerary-monument-model-verrocchio-andrea-del/?carousel-image=2006AE9603}. Use permitted for non-commercial publishing.

Latex puts a line break before the ac. and before the ? but that's much too long.
(The printer is using my PDFs).

I tried putting \ before verrocchio; the result was a single \ and no break.
I tried \newline, but that won't work inside \url{}.
I tried putting a blank line before verrocchio; Latex ignored it.

Comment: The book will be in print so I don't really need the hyperlinks.

Comment: Please tell us how you build the bibliography: Entirely by hand, or with software such as BibTeX or biber/biblatex? If you employ software, do you load the `xurl` or the `url` package (or neither)? If you employ the `url` package, please tell us about the options you load the package with. How or where is `\figc` defined?

Comment: Entirely by hand. I load \usepackage{url} with no options that I know of.

Comment: What happens if you replace `\usepackage{url}` with `\usepackage{xurl}` and recompile your document?